# How to structure products/orders in a firestore model?

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

So I'm creating a vue.js app and using Firebase as a back-end service. I have gotten some knowledge now on how one can store data in firestore but I'm asking what way would be the best for my case. At a certain point in the app, users can complete orders where each order has certain products. Every order will have an average of let's say 5/6 products, which are objects. Which of the following ways to strcture this data would you suggest?

1. orderedProducts as a top-level collection: here every document in this collection would have a reference to the order. Since I only need the products related to one order, I think this would be a bad choice. The relation is somewhat gone?
2. subcollection: here products can be a subcollection of orders. Nice hierarchy / structure but increases document reads compared to embedded array.
3. array: products is embedded as an array inside an order document. This is what I have now and is the easiest approach to create.

I thought, since the amount of products per order will be rather slim, I just use an array of products inside my order document. But ofcourse I might be wrong, or missing some important stuff.
I would appreciate any help/pointers on this real-life example on how to structure these products per order.

Thanks!

Comment: We are usually structuring a Firestore database according to the queries that we want to perform. What are those queries?

Comment: Now that you tell me: every order is also related to a merchant. So I want to fetch all orders for a merchant. Then also per order I want to fetch all products in that order. And that is pretty much it.

Comment: Ok, I will write you an answer right away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible schema for your app's use-case might be:

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- merchants (collection)
   |     |
   |     --- merchantId (document)
   |           |
   |           --- //merchant details
   |
   --- orders (collection)
         |
         --- orderId (document)
               |
               --- merchantId: "LongMerchantId"
               |
               --- products (array)
                     |
                     --- 0
                     |   |
                     |   --- productName: "Bacon"
                     |   |
                     |   --- productPrice: 5
                     |
                     --- 1
                         |
                         --- productName: "Eggs"
                         |
                         --- productPrice: 12
```

Using this structure you can easily query for all orders of a single merchant:

```
db.collection("orders").whereEqualTo("merchantId", "LongMerchantId");
```

To get all the products of a particular order, simply use the following reference:

```
DocumentReference orderIdRef = db.collection("orders").document("orderId");
```

Now you can attach a listener on this reference, get the document and use the products list. You didn't specify the programming language that you are using so I gave you the examples in Android. It's very simple to transform them in the language you are using. For Android, to get a list of custom objects, please check the following article:

- [How to map an array of objects from Cloud Firestore to a List of objects?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-map-an-array-of-objects-from-cloud-firestore-to-a-list-of-objects-122e579eae10)

One more thing to note is that the solution above will work **only** if you are sure that products in an order will fit in a [1 MiB (1,048,576 bytes)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#limits). If you are not sure, instead of an array you should use a sub-collection. If you want to be 100% safe, you can always check against the maximum quota, using [FirestoreDocument-Android library](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreDocument-Android/tree/master/firestore-document).

Comment: Hello Alex, thank you for your elaborated answer. I am using vue.js so I use the javascript sdk. The structure you show makes sense indeed. Why did you opt there for orders being a top-level collection, and not a subcollection of a merchant? Also, I will want to create a listener to notify a merchant of a new order that belongs to him, does this change any of the above logic that you wrote? Thanks!

Comment: Hey Niels! I decided to add the `orders` collection as a top-level collection because it's easier (in my opinion) to work with such a flatten structure. It's not wrong to add it as a sub-collection, in that case, a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) will be required and not a simple query. The queries will be fast in both cases. Regarding the last, question, no there is no change that you need to make.